# Динамический выпадающий список с данными из mysql на php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Помогите реализовать задачу, иметься таблица в базе данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно реализовать выпадающее меню в таблице, где можно выбрать пользователя из бд и выведутся его данные, заполнив таблицу.
На данный момент все выглядит примерно так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю как можно это реализовать, что бы у поля "Имя" была стрелочка при нажатии на которую открывался список всех пользователей в бд, и если выбрать другого пользователя, то будут загружены его данные в таблицу.

Ниже представлен код

```
<?php
$servername = "x";
$database = "x";
$username = "x";
$password = "x";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database); 

$name = $_GET['name_surname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$delivery = $_GET['browser'];
$adres = $_GET['address'];
$model_phone = $_GET['iphone'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (name, email, type_phone, delivery, address, model) 
        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$type', '$delivery','$adres', '$model_phone')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Ваши данные представлены ниже:<br/>";
} else {
      echo "Ошибка: <br/>" . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>',"Имя: ",'</td>';
        echo '<td>',($_GET['name_surname']),'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>',"Ваш email: ",'</td>';
        echo '<td>',($_GET['email']),'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>',"Вы заказали: ",'</td>';
        echo '<td>',($_GET['type']) . " ". $_GET['iphone'], " iPhone",'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>',"Способ доставки: ",'</td>';
        echo '<td>',($_GET['browser']),'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>',"Адрес доставки: ",'</td>';
        echo '<td>',($_GET['address']),'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью json подгружаете с бд

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Имя:</td>
        <td>
            <select>
            <?php
                foreach ($row as $key => $val1) {
                    foreach ($val1 as $val2) {
                        echo "<option name='$val2'>$val2</option>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ваш email</td>
        <td><?=$row['email'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Вы заказали:</td>
        <td><?=$row['type'] ?><?=$row['iphone'] ?> iPhone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Способ доставки:</td>
        <td><?=$row['browser'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Адрес доставки:</td>
        <td><?=$row['address'] ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Можно чуть-чуть конкретнее

Comment: @AndreyDolgopolov почти все написал, теперь при изменении имени делайте запрос к бд по id с помощью json и обновляйте

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$conn1 = new mysqli('192.168.0.1', 'login', '***', 'tabl');
// Check connection
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 

 mysqli_set_charset($conn1,"utf8");

$query = "select * from clients";
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$arr[]=$row;
$arrs[]=$row['name'];
}

echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 400px">';
echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">';

 $name=array('id' => 'Идентификатор', 'name'=>'Имя', 'email'=>'Почтовый адрес', 'type_phone'=>'Тип телефона', 'delivery'=>'Доставка', 'address'=>'адрес', 'model'=>'модель');
foreach ($arr[0] as $key => $value) 
{
if($key=='name'){
echo'<tr>';


echo '<td style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.$name[$key].' Выбор имени:  ';

echo '<select name="hero">';
foreach ($arrs as $key1 => $value1) {
echo'<option value='.$value1.'>'.$value1.'</option>';
    
}
echo '/<select>';

echo '<br><input type="submit" value="Отправить">';
echo'<td style="width: 100px;" >'.$value.'</td>';
echo'</tr>';

}else{
echo'<tr>';
echo '<td style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.$name[$key].'<select><td style="width: 100px;">'.$value.'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}
}
echo '</form>';
echo'</table>';



if(isset($_POST['hero'])){
$data=$_POST['hero'];

$conn1 = new mysqli('192.168.0.1', 'login', '***', 'tabl');
// Check connection
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 

 mysqli_set_charset($conn1,"utf8");


$query = "select * from clients where name='".$data."'";
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
//print_r($row)."<br>\n";
$arr1[]=$row1;
//$arrs[]=$row['name'];
}


 echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">';
 $name1=array('id' => 'Идентификатор', 'name'=>'Имя', 'email'=>'Почтовый адрес', 'type_phone'=>'Тип телефона', 'delivery'=>'Доставка', 'address'=>'адрес', 'model'=>'модель');
foreach ($arr1 as $key2 => $value2) 
{

 echo'<tr>';

echo '<td style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.$name1[$key2].'<select><td style="width: 100px;">'.$value2.'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}


echo'</table>';
echo '<br>';
}

?>
```